# cryptsetup, LUKS, dm-crypt benchmark

Tags: luks, cryptsetup, dm-crypt, benchmark

I'm working on embedded software, where I used the cryptsetup to create an encrypted disk space over a NFS ethernet standard connection... I'm interested to understand the writing speed that this disk achieves (simple performance analysis).
First I run a standard benchmark

```
root@sbc-lynx:/mnt# cryptsetup benchmark                                        
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
PBKDF2-sha1        33098 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha256      52851 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha512      34492 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-ripemd160   29789 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-whirlpool    7062 iterations per second for 256-bit key
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-cbc   128b    26.7 MiB/s    24.5 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   128b     6.6 MiB/s     7.3 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   128b    10.2 MiB/s    11.0 MiB/s
     aes-cbc   256b    21.4 MiB/s    20.8 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   256b     6.6 MiB/s     7.3 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   256b    10.2 MiB/s    10.2 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b     9.0 MiB/s     9.0 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   256b     7.0 MiB/s     7.2 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   256b    10.7 MiB/s    10.9 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b     7.1 MiB/s     7.0 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   512b     7.0 MiB/s     7.1 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   512b    10.7 MiB/s    10.9 MiB/s
```

Just for the testing purpose I choose to se eaes-cbc-256 that seems to have good performances.
But now I want to test the real speed achieved. my NFS is mounted in /mnt/ and the encrypted folder is correctly mounted in /home/encryptroot/ . I used:

```
time dd bs=5M count=1 if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/ppx conv=fsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
real    0m0.556s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.110s

time dd bs=5M count=1 if=/dev/zero of=/home/encryptroot/ppx conv=fsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out   
real    0m1.104s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.180s
```

From these results I obtained in normal folder a speed of almost 9 MB/s
While for the encrypted folder I obtained 4 MB/s
Question1) Is this a valid method to evaluate writing speed? using the param fsync this should evaluate the time used to really copy the file in disk (not to copy in caches)?

I'm not satisfied by this results, because with a potential of 20 MB/s encryption I can't fill the total bandwidth available (around 9 MB/s).

Final investigation: I changed the cipher and used the default aes-xts that should achieve a max of 9MB/s I repeated

```
time dd bs=5M count=1 if=/dev/zero of=/home/encryptroot/ppx conv=fsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out

real    0m2.281s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.180s
```

Obtaining a writing speed of 2.2 MB/s.
Question2) there are other factors to consider that I'm missing to analyze these results? It's possible that the overhead of the xts is so high to reduce the throughput ? And have other test to suggest?

Thanks